# Is there a dynamic power consumption equation for RAM?

Tags: memory, electrical-power, memory-usage

How is the dynamic power consumption of memory determined . Can anybody give a canonical equation for power consumption of the RAM. What are the parameters involved in determing the dynamic power consumption of RAM ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Power consumption of RAM depends on multiple factors, off the top of my head: the memory module architecture, the specs of the chips used... Probably the most important factor is the way memory is being used - the pattern of writes to the memory cells - which depends on what's running on the CPU, so there's no way you're going to get a nice neat formula.

If you look at that rampedia page Wesley linked to, the last link on the page gives some sample calculations based on different scenarios of memory use.  If you wanted to do your own calculations, you'd have to come up with your own scenario and crunch the numbers.

If it were me, I'd use the "equation" of adding up the the power consumption given in the manufacturer's data sheets, e.g.  http://www.valueram.com/datasheets/KHX1600C8D3T1K2_4GX.pdf

Relative to the CPU, graphics, and fans, the power consumption of RAM is pretty small, so the spec sheets are probably good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article over at RAMpedia: http://www.rampedia.com/index.php/power-consumption

I'd copy portions of it, but that would be needless. In short, it depends on what vendor and RAM type you use. I do not know of an accurate general equation that can be used. It's complicated and unless you're building a cluster with PB of RAM and have to calculate your usage within a mW, it's not a big deal. =)